# Open Emacs with --debug-init on OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, emacs, debug

I am trying to debug `why my .emacs does not load.` Error message.

```
Invalid read syntax: # ... Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

My question is: How do I do that?
What I've tried so far is this.

open -a --debug-init Emacs.app

```
Unable to find application named '--debug-init'
```

open -a Emacs.app --debug-init

```
open: unrecognized option `--debug-init'
```

I have my emacs configuration file in my home directory.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not on a Mac right now so I can't check, but this should work:

```
open -a /Applications/Emacs.app --args --debug-init
```

Note: requires Snow Leopard and later.

EDIT: You can also try this:

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/emacs --debug-init
```

If that doesn't work, try capitalizing the "E" in "emacs". (I'm not sure how Emacs.app is structured internally, but the core executable should probably be one of the two.)

Comment: Many thanks, it is working! Accepting when I've solved the error.

Comment: Which one of the two worked? (Still not at my Mac ATM)

Comment: Both two gives exactly the same result. Success!